# Clarify an old answer: Why we can let $\vert x \vert = \frac{1}{1+t}$ for $\vert x \vert <1$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am looking for a clarification on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/197612/344247) about why $\lim_{n\to\infty}nx^n=0$.

Specifically, the answer has two aspects I am concerned about: First, the answer begins by saying

> We prove the result under the slightly weaker condition $|x|\lt 1$.
>
> Let $|x|=\dfrac{1}{1+t}$. Then $t\gt 0$.

**Why can we let $\vert x\vert = \frac{1}{1+t}$**?,

- And $t>0$ because $\vert x\vert$ must be positive, correct?

Second, the answer claims

> By the Binomial Theorem, if $n \ge 2$, then
> $$(1+t)^n \ge 1+nt +\frac{n(n-1)}{2}t^2 \gt \frac{n(n-1)}{2}t^2.$$

**Why is the first inequality weak?** We are leaving off terms from the binomial formula, and $t>0$, so shouldn't it be $>$ (strict)?

Note: The original answerer has not be active in over a year, which is why I post here rather than leave a comment.

Comment: In that first case you can actually just solve for $t$, but even if you couldn't do this algebraically you can still make such a substitution for a monotone function by using the intermediate value theorem. As for the second thing, since $t>0$ the inequality is strict as soon as $n>2$. This is really nitpicking though because the strictness isn't needed for the argument at all.

Comment: "Why can we let |x|=1/1+t?".  Because if $0< |x| < 1$ then  $\frac 1{|x|} > 1$.  And $\frac 1{|x|} - 1 > 0$.  So let $t = \frac 1{|x|} - 1; t > 0$ then $|x| = \frac 1{1+t}; t> 0$.

Comment: "We are leaving off terms from the binomial formula, and t>0, so shouldn't it be > (strict)?"  Only if $n > 2$ if $n = 2$ it's an equality.

Comment: "And t>0 because |x| must be positive, correct?"  Not really.  $t > 0$ because we are assuming $|x| < 1$.

Comment: @Ian Sorry, you lost me when talking about substituting for monotone function. You are just saying that since $\frac{1}{1+t}$ is monotone, I can find values of $t$ such that $\frac{1}{1+t} <\vert x\vert$ and another value $t'\not=t$ such that $\frac{1}{1+t}>\vert x\vert$ and then by IVT there is a $t''$ such that $\frac{1}{1+t} =\vert x\vert$?

Comment: @user106860 Yes, that's right, and $t''$ is unique as a solution to the equation.

Comment: @Ian Thank you c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $t$ has to be non-negative because $\;0<|x|=\dfrac1{1+t}<1$, so the denominator has to be  $>1$.
2. The first inequality is weak because it's an equality if these are the only terms of the binomial expansion, which happens if $n=2$.